# How to read just one character on a text File (or few characters) without using readLine() method?

Tags: java, file

I need to read only one character in a text File. Inside my method I've already have the BufferedReader object with the resource inside.

[image]

I can't read the line because my text file is ebcdic and it has more than 2GB on the same line.
There's no another line.
The object String doesn't support more than 2GB.

I need to check the first characters.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

I've tried to use the Scanner object and its methods but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) instead of `readLine`?

Comment: `read(char[])` is what you need, as @CharlesMager says. Create a `String` from the array

Comment: Any of the other `read` methods of `Reader` can be used. If you don't need `readLine` you can also just leave out the `BufferedReader` entirely. Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)